# While loop doesnt end in iterative binary search

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

I'm currently writing a binary search that uses iteration instead of recursion and its not returning anything. I've debugged it down to the while loop not ending but I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong.

Here is the code:

```
public static <E extends Comparable> boolean binarySearchIterative(E[] array, E obj) {
    int first = 0;
    int last = array.length - 1;
    while(first <= last) {
        int middle = (first + last) / 2;
        if(array[middle].equals(obj)) return true;
        else if(obj.compareTo(array[middle]) < 0) first = middle - 1;
        else first = middle + 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And yes, my list is ordered ;)

Comment: doesn't integer division always truncate the remainder? In that case `middle + 1` would never become greater than `last`

Comment: Your statement in `else if` should be `last = middle -1;` Not first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second `else if` part you need to set `last` instead of `first` -

```
else if(obj.compareTo(array[middle]) < 0) last = middle - 1;
```